# Nuitka ошибка fake_useragent

Tags: python, nuitka

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет, возникла проблема когда компилирую свой код python -m nuitka --mingw64 --onefile --windows-icon-from-ico="C:\Program Files\Парсер METRO\icon.ico" --plugin-enable=tk-inter --run METRO.py.
Сам код рабочий ошибок не возникает.
Ошибка возникает при запуске exe файла когда прогоняю его через nuitka
Хочу добавить что fake_useragent у меня установлен, но правильный путь к нему C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Lib\site-packages\fake_useragent\data.

C:\Users\Vova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1 - такой папки у меня вообще нет, не понимаю почему Nuitka пытался найти fake_useragent по этому пути..

```
Unable to find local data/json file or could not parse the contents using importlib-resources. Try pkg-resource next. Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\fake_useragent\utils.py", line 21, in load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Vova\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ONEFIL~1\\fake_useragent \\data\\browsers.json"
Could not find local data/json file or could not parse the contents using pkg-resource.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\fake_useragent\utils.py", line 21, in load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Vova\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ONEFIL~1\\fake_useragent \\data\\browsers.json"
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\fake_useragent\utils.py", line 36, in load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Vova\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ONEFIL~1\\fake_useragent \\data\\browsers.json"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Wova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\metro.py", line 168, in <module>
ua-UserAgent()
File "C:\Users\Vova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\fake_useragent\fake.py", line 56, in File "C:\Users\Vova\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL-1\fake_useragent\utils.py", line 52, in load
init
fake_useragent.errors. FakeUserAgentError: ('Data list is empty', None)
```